# colortbl: \rowcolor in tables with \begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}

Tags: tables, colortbl

I'm trying to make a table with the following code:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
  \hline 
  \rowcolor[gray]{.9} a & b & c \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Unfortunately the `\rowcolor` command seems to not care about the empty leading and ending spaces in the table, i.e. the `@{}`'s in the `tabular` 'preamble'.

Any suggestions to overcome this issue are most welcome.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\newcolumntype{C}{c<{\kern\tabcolsep}@{}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}CCc@{}}\hline 
  \rowcolor[gray]{.9}[0pt][0pt] a & b & c \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution! I actually ended up using:

    \newcolumntype{C}{c<{\kern\tabcolsep}<{\kern\tabcolsep}@{}}

since it gave me the same distance between columns.

Comment: I think it would make more sense logically to define two new columns `L` and `R` (say) - for the left and right no-overhang columns - as `\newcolumntype{L}{>{\hspace*{-\tabcolsep}}c}` and `\newcolumntype{R}{c<{\hspace*{-\tabcolsep}}}` and use `\begin{tabular}{L..R}` *without* the additional `\rowcolor` options. That is, just `\rowcolor[gray]{.9}`.

Comment: Works like a charm! And I even understand what the code does :-)

Answer (score 4):

From the userguide of the `colortbl` package (which provides the commands `\columncolor` and `\rowcolor`):

> `\rowcolor` takes the same argument forms as `\columncolor`. It must be used
>   at the start of a row. If the optional overhang arguments are not used the overhangs
>   will default to ... **\tabcolsep** ... [emphasis added]

Here, the length `\tabcolsep` is (half) the width of the intercolumn white space, and equals 6pt by default. However, specifying the `\rowcolor` command as

```
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}[][] % empty contents resolve to 0[pt]
```

will not produce what you're after either, I'm guessing, because this will leave white gaps in the table's two interior columns. The `colortbl` package doesprovides a `\cellcolor` command, but unfortunately this command doesn't take left- or right-hand trimming options, so you'd be back where you started out with.

In short, if you insist on using the `\rowcolor` command, you're probably best served by omitting the `@{}` specifiers at the far left and far right of the `tabular` specification.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. That fact that \tabcolsep equals half the width of the intercolumn white space helped me to modify Herbert's solution such that the intercolumn white space is unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

With the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have directly the expected result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}ccc@{}}[colortbl-like]\hline 
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}a & b & c \\\hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You do not need `colortbl` but you need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]