# color not applied properly in a row when \extraccolsep\fill is used in the tabular* environment

Tags: tables, colortbl

In my article, I am trying to apply a color for a row in the table, when I am using `\extracolsep\fill` to fit the table to the text width, the rowcolor is splitted wherever the extra space added by a `\extracolsep\fill`. Is it possible to get the color shade without split by the automated way?

I am having lot of table in my article, I need to align the numbers by decimal, so I have added `dcolumn.sty` also. How can we get this color shaded without splitted by the automated way? Any trick is available?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage[table,dvips]{xcolor}
\usepackage{showframe}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\rowcolors{2}{gray!35}{gray!70}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep\fill}d{3,0}d{2,0}d{3,0}d{2,0}d{2,0}d{3,0}d{3,0}d{3,0}}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{blue!50}128&64&32&16&8&400&200&100\\
  \hline
  1   &0  &1   &1  &0  &1  &0  &1\\\hline
  1   &0  &100 &1  &0  &1  &0  &1\\\hline
  100 &0  &52  &1  &0  &1  &0  &1\\\hline
  1   &0  &1   &1  &0  &1  &0  &1\\\hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I am getting this output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Could [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89679/101651) help you?

Comment: @CarLaTeX I am using `\rowcolors{2}{gray!35}{gray!70}` from xcolor package to get the alternative color for a row, the above solution we need to go and give the command by the manual way in each and every row, and this solution is not working for a para align mode when the column is breaking a two or more line

Comment: @CarLaTeX  we can get the the solution by using \tabcolsep, but we need to do more adjustment and more compilation to fix the table to the width, this will take so much time, i having more than 100 tables, it will be a tedious work. I am trying to get by the automated way!!!

Comment: @CarLaTeX Unfortunately the \rowcolor command seems to not care about the empty leading and ending spaces in the table, i.e. the `@{}`'s in the tabular 'preamble'. when I am using the `@{}` the color shade is going beyond the table width

Answer (score 1):

The `siunitx` package offers the possibility to choose the width of `S` columns. Here is a solution with this package – and colours to my taste ;o)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx, siunitx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
  \sisetup{table-format=3.0, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=\dimexpr0.125\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
  \rowcolors{2}{Gainsboro!80!Lavender}{Gainsboro!60!LightSteelBlue}
  \begin{tabular}{SS[table-format=2.0]SS[table-format=2.0]S[table-format=2.0]SSS}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{RoyalBlue!80} 128 & 64 & 32 & 16 & 8 & 400 & 200 & 100 \\
    \hline
    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\%\hline
    1 & 0 & 100 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\%\hline
    100 & 0 & 52 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\%\hline
    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]