# rowcolor command from colortbl package leaves unwanted gaps in shading between columns

Tags: tables, booktabs, colortbl, threeparttable, rowcolor

I would like to highlight the first two rows of my table with a custom shade of gray. For this, I thought of using the `\rowcolor` environment from the `colortbl` package.

However, its usage seems to leave unwanted gaps in the shading, i.e. the shading patch does not get applied to the full row.

Here is a `MWE`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{newgray}{RGB}{196,196,196}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} l c r}
        \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Random Table}} \\
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{Item} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Case 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Case 2} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Case 3}\\
        \midrule

        \rowcolor{newgray}first thing, & \tnote{a}245  & \tnote{b}25e-6  & \tnote{c}79e-6 \\
        \rowcolor{newgray}[20pt][20pt]second thing & \tnote{a}450  & ---             & \tnote{b}24e-6 \\
        third thing                    & \tnote{d}2e-6 & \tnote{c}4123.5 & \tnote{b}2e-6  \\
        fourth thing                   & ---           & 1e6             & no data        \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \medskip
    \begin{tablenotes}
    \item[a] some explanation
    \item[b] this is why \dots
    \item[c] see reference awesome
    \item[d] hello world
    \item
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following output

[image: rowcolor not uniformly shading the row]

Here are the requirements. I would like to have the table typeset to the `textwidth` achieved here using `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} l c r}`,  and secondly I need to have explanatory notes achieved here using the `tablenotes` environment provided by the `threeparttable` package. For aesthetics, I am using the `booktabs` package.

Clearly, the shading achieved right now is not desirable. When used without any overhang specification, the `\rowcolor` command leaves gaps in the shading. While, using left and right overhang minimises these shading gaps in the middle columns, it extends the shading beyond the table's width, which is undesirable.

**How can I achieve the expected behavior, i.e. shade the row uniformly, with no gaps and without exceeding table's width?**

Comment: Using `tabularx` to make the table span the textwidth does not seem to have this drawback. Would this be an option for you?

Comment: @leandriis I heard that there is no point in specifying ```X X X ``` for all columns in tabularx. Maybe I am wrong. Anyway, I am curious to know your solution.

Comment: cause of your problem is `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`.

Comment: @Zarko I see. How would I overcome this problem?

Comment: @Krishna: My suggestion would have been what you already guessed: Using four `X` type columns. Here are also some related topics: [color not applied properly in a row when \extraccolsep\fill is used in the tabular* environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/354425/134144) and [coloring entire row of tabular*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89679/134144)

Comment: @leandriis the second link was very useful. Thank you. How would I use four ```X``` type columns and still retain the desired alignment of ```l l c r``` ?

Comment: @Krishna: You can for example define your own column type based on the `X` type as shown here [Centering in tabularx and X columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89932/134144) for a centered `X`like column. For raggedright or raggedleft alignment, this works analogously.

Comment: @leandriis that is awesome. However, the custom patch [in the second link you referred me](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89679/coloring-entire-row-of-tabular) solved the issue for me. Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environments `{NiceTabular}` and `{NiceTabular*}` of `nicematrix` provide tools to color cells, rows and columns without the drawbacks of `colortbl`.

Here, you have directly the expected result (but you need several commpilations).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{threeparttable}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular*}{\textwidth}{ l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} l c r}%
  [code-before = \rowcolor[RGB]{196,196,196}{3,4}]
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Random Table}} \\
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Item} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Case 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Case 2} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Case 3}\\
\midrule
first thing, & \tnote{a}245  & \tnote{b}25e-6  & \tnote{c}79e-6 \\
second thing & \tnote{a}450  & ---             & \tnote{b}24e-6 \\
third thing                    & \tnote{d}2e-6 & \tnote{c}4123.5 & \tnote{b}2e-6  \\
fourth thing                   & ---           & 1e6             & no data        \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular*}
\medskip
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] some explanation
\item[b] this is why \dots
\item[c] see reference awesome
\item[d] hello world
\item
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{document}
```

[image: Ouput of the above code]

Answer (score 4):

- `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` introduce additional space between columns which is not covered by `rowcolor`
- in second line you have `\rowcolor{newgray}[20pt][20pt]` which should be only `\rowcolor{newgray}`
- coloring rows and use rules from `booktabs` doesn't gives nice result, instead them i suggest lines provided by package `boldline`
- for more vertical space in cells i suggest to use `calspace`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % it call and enhance colortbl
\definecolor{newgray}{RGB}{196,196,196}
\usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}       % new
\usepackage{boldline}       % new (part of shipunov bundle)
\usepackage{cellspace}      % new
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ S{>{\hsize=0.4\hsize}L}
                                >{\hsize=0.2\hsize}L
                                >{\hsize=0.2\hsize}C
                                >{\hsize=0.2\hsize}R}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Random Table}}                               \\
    \hlineB{2}
        Item    & Case 1        &   Case 2          &   Case 3          \\
    \hlineB{1.75}
    \rowcolor{newgray}
first thing,    & \tnote{a}245  & \tnote{b}25e-6    & \tnote{c}79e-6    \\
    \rowcolor{newgray}
second thing    & \tnote{a}450  & ---               & \tnote{b}24e-6    \\
third thing     & \tnote{d}2e-6 & \tnote{c}4123.5   & \tnote{b}2e-6     \\
fourth thing    & ---           & 1e6               & no data           \\
    \hlineB{2}
    \end{tabularx}

    \begin{tablenotes}
    \item[a] some explanation
    \item[b] this is why \dots
    \item[c] see reference awesome
    \item[d] hello world
    \item
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{document}
```

**edit:**
if you like to have simpler solution with less nice table (which width is still equal to text width), than try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  % it call and enhance colortbl
\definecolor{newgray}{RGB}{196,196,196}
\usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}       % new
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ L L C R }
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Random Table}}                               \\
    \hline
        Item    & Case 1        &   Case 2          &   Case 3          \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{newgray}
first thing,    & \tnote{a}245  & \tnote{b}25e-6    & \tnote{c}79e-6    \\
    \rowcolor{newgray}
second thing    & \tnote{a}450  & ---               & \tnote{b}24e-6    \\
third thing     & \tnote{d}2e-6 & \tnote{c}4123.5   & \tnote{b}2e-6     \\
fourth thing    & ---           & 1e6               & no data           \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] some explanation
\item[b] this is why \dots
\item[c] see reference awesome
\item[d] hello world
\item
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{document}
```

note:

- `S{X}` specifier means that to selected `X` column is added vertical space defined by

  ```
  \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
  \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
  ```
- with `>{\hsize=0.4\hsize}` and `>{\hsize=0.2\hsize}` is changed ratio between columns widths (first column has width equal `0.4\textwidth`, other three have width equal `0.2\textwidth` each)
- the first solution can be simplified by removing `cellspace` stuff and for more vertical spaces around cells contents use simpler `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}`:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[table]{xcolor} % it call and enhance colortbl
  \definecolor{newgray}{RGB}{196,196,196}
  \usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable}
  \usepackage{tabularx}       % new
  \usepackage{boldline}       % new (part of shipunov bundle)
  \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
  \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
  \newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{threeparttable}
      \centering
      \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=0.4\hsize}L
                               >{\hsize=0.2\hsize}L
                               >{\hsize=0.2\hsize}C
                               >{\hsize=0.2\hsize}R}

   %% table body and table notes %%

  \end{threeparttable}
  \end{document}
  ```

Comment: it is not clear what the ```{ S{>{\hsize=0.4\hsize}L}
                                >{\hsize=0.2\hsize}L
                                >{\hsize=0.2\hsize}C
                                >{\hsize=0.2\hsize}R}``` commands are doing here.  Can you provide a simpler example without using these commands ?

Comment: it will become more clear after reading documentation for packages `cellspace` and `tabularx` :-). see edited answer.

Comment: thank you very much for the edits clarifying the question. Much appreciate your efforts.