# Beamer and longtable

Tags: tables, beamer, longtable, highlighting

I am trying to highlight a row in beamer, but the whole row does not get hihglighted (i.e., there is white space between each column). **Is there any way to highlight the entire row by still using the long table?** Please also note that there are many other slides, so I had to use many packages that may not seem relevant here. Here is what I have of far:

```
\documentclass[table,slidestop,compress,mathserif, 10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable}
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=custom,width=16,height=9,scale=0.5,debug]{beamerposter} 


% The main document
\begin{document}






\setcounter{subsection}{1}
\begin{frame}{Regression}
\vspace{-0.50cm}
\begin{table}[htb]
\footnotesize   

  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l*{6}{Y}}

     \toprule 
    & \mcc{(I)} & \mcc{(II)} & \mcc{(III)} & \mcc{(IV)} & \mcc{(V)}& \mcc{(VI)}   \\\hline 
\rowcolor{blue!20} $\mathbbm{1}$(Hosp$_{i})\times\mathbbm{1}$(Doc$_{t}$)  & 3.333***&6.333***& 7.333*** & 7.334***& 6.353*** & 6.333*** \\
\rowcolor{blue!10}  & (0.111) &(0.112)& (0.112) & (0.113) & (0.173)& (0.178) \\\addlinespace
\midrule
\textbf{Health Variables}  
      &        &     &          & {X}       & {X}    & {X}    \\ 

 \midrule

\textbf{Other Effects} \\
Time 
    &           & {X}       &     &    &  {X}            \\
Location
    &           &           &      {X}    & &  & {X}            \\
\midrule
Number  & {11,210} & {11,210} & {11,210} & {10,504} &{10,504} &{10,504}  \\
 K-Number  & {63.11} & {61.33}  & {58.33}  & {56.01}  & {50.93} & {53.77}  \\ 
 \hline
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to a minimal version. You load many unrelated packages, some of them even twice.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, just modified it and removed all irrelevant parts.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, when I remove the other parts, the issue seems to disappear but if I remove them in the original document, things get really messy. I am not sure where the original error was in.

Comment: I added back the other parts since I cannot construct the whole presentation otherwise..

Comment: The original error is [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/354425/194703), I think. There are, however, better fixes for your situation. More importantly, this site is not about you nor me, it is about everyone. If someone writes an answer keeping all these packages, this may serve you, perhaps, but no one else. Cooking it down to a minimal content will allow others to benefit from the thread, too.

Comment: Thanks, I will remove the packages that are not needed. I believe, I found the command that causes the error: 

\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=custom,width=16,height=9,scale=0.5,debug]{beamerposter} 

However, once I delete this command, the format of the beamer gets messed up.

Comment: I think that the problem is that `\rowcolor` is not trained to collaborate with `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`. If you remove this, the problem disappears but the table does no longer fill the full page width.

Comment: Interesting. There is no way to get around this issue? By the way, I have removed all comments that are not needed. The errors disappeared this way.

Comment: AFAIK there is no always working way, only partial solutions. One can marry the `X` column of a `tabularx` to `S` (you do not need a `longrable` here) but it seems that [the cleanest solutions here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12663/194703) do not want to collaborate with `beamer` / your document.  BTW, I do not see how you got rid of unused packages and libraries, you do not use `tikz` here but load `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}` twice.

Comment: Following your suggestion, I completely changed the setting to the tabularx setting. However, there is one minor issue now. The highlighting does not span the entire row. There is a small non-highlighted area towards the end of the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick search and it seems that there is a big conundrum concerning `colortbl`, the trick you employ to make the table fill the full page, and using the features of the `S` column of `siunitx`, in particular when paired with beamer. One probably can pair the solutions by our moderators from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12663/194703) with a `fragile` frame (I did not try, without `fragile` it obviously won't work). But I came across several statements by rather seasoned users from this site who say that `colortbl` is never perfect, one may use `tikz` instead, which you seem to already loading. So the solution is to use `tikzpagenodes` and the `tikzmark` library to locally switch on a background of these colors. For this it is necessary to drop the `table` option from `\documentclass[table,slidestop,compress,mathserif, 10pt]{beamer}`, and to reset the background in the subsequent frame.

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif, 10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{array}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=custom,width=16,height=9,scale=0.5,debug]{beamerposter} 

% Custom numbering for the footline
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \raisebox{5pt}{%
    \makebox[\paperwidth]{%
      \hfill\makebox[7pt]{%
        \tiny\insertframenumber
      }
    }
  }
}
\definecolor{dgreen}{rgb}{0.,0.6,0.}
\definecolor{dblue}{rgb}{0.,0.,0.6}
\definecolor{dred}{rgb}{0.6,0.,0.}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{eso-pic}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Test}

\end{frame}


\setbeamertemplate{background}{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \fill[blue!20] (current page text area.west|-row1.south)
 rectangle (current page text area.east|-row1.north);
 \fill[blue!10] (current page text area.west|-row2.south)
 rectangle (current page text area.east|-row2.north);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\setcounter{subsection}{9}
\begin{frame}{Regression}

\begingroup
\footnotesize
\sisetup{table-format=1.4,
         table-space-text-pre=(,
         table-space-text-post=***,
         table-align-text-post=false,
         input-symbols=(),
         table-alignment=right
         }
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
 \vspace*{-0.53cm}
    \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l
                                           *{6}{S}}
     \toprule  
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
    & \mcc{(I)} & \mcc{(II)} & \mcc{(III)} & \mcc{(IV)} & \mcc{(V)} & \mcc{(VI)}  \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot 
\tikzmarknode{row1}{\strut} $\mathds{1}$(Hospital$_{i})\times\mathds{1}$(Doctor$_{t}$)  & 3.333***&6.333***& 7.333*** & 7.334***& 6.353*** & 6.333*** \\
\tikzmarknode{row2}{\strut} & (0.111) &(0.112)& (0.112) & (0.113) & (0.173)& (0.178) \\\addlinespace


 \midrule
\textbf{Health Variables}  
      &        &     &          & {X}       & {X}    & {X}    \\ 

 \midrule

\textbf{Other Effects} \\
Time 
    &           & {X}       &     &    &  {X}            \\
Location
    &           &           &      {X}    & &  & {X}            \\
\midrule
Number  & {11,210} & {11,210} & {11,210} & {10,504} &{10,504} &{10,504}  \\
 K-Number  & {63.11} & {61.33}  & {58.33}  & {56.01}  & {50.93} & {53.77}  \\ 
 \hline
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{frame}


\setbeamertemplate{background}{}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Another test}

\end{frame}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also replaced `mathbbm` by `mathds` because its glyphs are very similar but not pixelated, and so on. However, I did not completely tune this answer.

Comment: I hope that not the usual thing happens that someone comes, makes minor adjustments and sells it as their solution. There are many alternative ways of answering this question.

Comment: This is really helpful, many thanks!!!