# Where Did My $ Go?

Tags: color, tabularx

Don't worry its not a problem of `$` being a special character (or at least I think). For some reason the $ that is supposed to show up next to the total on the last line does not. Removing either the `\cellcolor` commands or the `@{}` in the `tubularx` definition makes it show up. Why is this happening and how can I get my $ back?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{Xc@{}r}
  TEST && 1000 \\
  ANOTHER TEST && 5000 \\
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{TOTAL} & \cellcolor{blue!25!white} \textdollar & \cellcolor{blue!25!white} 6000\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is covered by the padding in the last column: `colortbl` apply a padding notwithstanding a `@{}` specification.

Comment: @egreg Is there a way to get no padding and still have colored cells?

Comment: Is there something preventing you from keeping the middle column empty and writing `\cellcolor{blue!25!white}\textdollar 6000` in the final column?

Comment: @Mico I would love for the dollar sign to be left aligned while the amount right aligned. Perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: @cabellicar123 - `\cellcolor{blue!25!white}\textdollar\hspace*{\fill} 6000` should work, right?

Comment: @Mico I seem to be getting strange results when using that.

Comment: "seem to be getting strange results" is not exactly specific, let alone actionable. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Mico My apologies it is rather unspecific. I modified the number in the first row of the table to be `1000000000` to better demonstrate the issue. The `$` is placed too far right. The color seems to start in the correct place, but does not cover the entire cell (the last `0` in `6000` is not covered with color).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\cellcolor` applies a padding and so your dollar sign ends up below this padding and so it's invisible.

A variant of an [answer by Herbert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35180/4427) seems to solve the issue. I reduced the width just to make a smaller picture; the figures are incorrect, of course.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{.75\textwidth}{Xc>{\kern-2\tabcolsep}r}
  TEST && 10000000 \\
  ANOTHER TEST && 5000 \\
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{TOTAL} & \cellcolor{blue!25!white}\textdollar
& \cellcolor{blue!25!white}6000\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]