# Coloring a table row: color goes outside of table?

Tags: tables, rowcolor

I just finished up my table, but noticed that the coloring goes a bit too much "outside" of the table, to the left? Is there any fix for this?

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}llllll@{}}
\toprule
\rowcolor[HTML]{003085} 
{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Variables}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\textbf{Mean}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Median}} & \multicolumn{1}{c} 
{\cellcolor[HTML]{003085}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c] 
{@{}c@{}}Harm. \\ mean\end{tabular}}}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Std. \\ dev.\end{tabular}}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{003085}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}IQ \\ range\end{tabular}}}} \\ \midrule
Revenue & {\ul } & {\ul } & {\ul } & {\ul } & {\ul } \\
EBITDA & {\ul } & {\ul } & {\ul } & {\ul } & {\ul } \\
EV/EBIT N12M &  &  &  &  &  \\
EV/EBIT N24M &  &  &  &  &  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

Comment: Please reveal how `\ul` is defined.

Comment: Off-topic: Don't mix-and-mismatch visual metaphores: If you're going to highlight the header row by giving it a color, there's no need for `\toprule` and `\midrule`  to provide an additional visual highlight, or offset.

Comment: @Mico, thank you - you are absolutely right, it makes no sense. However, the \ul part I am quite unsure of how that is defined. I used the Tablegenerator from https://www.tablesgenerator.com/

Comment: tablesgenerator.com tells you exactly what is needed and how `\ul` is defined: `% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
% \useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}`

Comment: Thank you Leandriis, but I have already done that. :)

Comment: My comment was referring to your previous comment where you wrote: "However, the \ul part I am quite unsure of how that is defined".

Comment: You might want to have a look at: [colortbl: \rowcolor in tables with \begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35170/134144)

Answer (score 3):

The problem comes from your removing the padding at both ends of the table. Here is a work-around:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs} \def\ul{}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\cellgape}{\Gape[2pt]}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}}
\renewcommand{\theadset}{\cellcolor[HTML]{003085}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\cellcolor[HTML]{003085}\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}\bfseries}c}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\columncolor[HTML]{003085}[0pt][\tabcolsep]\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}\bfseries}l}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llllll@{}}
\toprule
 \multicolumn{1}{@{}L}{Variables} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{Median} & \multicolumn{1}{C}
{\makecell{Harm. \\ mean}} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{\makecell{Std. \\ dev.}} &
\multicolumn{1}{C}{\makecell{IQ \\ range}} \\ \midrule\addlinespace
Revenue & {\ul } & {\ul } & {\ul } & {\ul } & {\ul } \\
EBITDA & {\ul } & {\ul } & {\ul } & {\ul } & {\ul } \\
EV/EBIT N12M & & & & & \\
EV/EBIT N24M & & & & & \\ \addlinespace\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and its tools, you will have directly the expected output (and you won't see the thin white lines you see in some PDF viewers such as SumatraPDF).

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\newcommand{\headfont}{\color{white}\bfseries}
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}llllll@{}}
\CodeBefore
   \rowcolor[HTML]{003085}{1}
\Body
   \toprule
     \headfont Variables
   & \headfont Mean
   & \headfont Median
   & \Block{}<\headfont>{Harm. \\ mean} 
   & \Block{}<\headfont>{Std. \\ dev.} 
   & \Block{}<\headfont>{IQ \\ range} \\
   \midrule
   Revenue      \\
   EBITDA       \\
   EV/EBIT N12M \\
   EV/EBIT N24M \\ \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]