# \rowcolor and @{} issue

Tags: tables, arrays, rowcolor

In the next example we can see that
`\rowcolor` does not take into account the declaration `@{}` in `tabular` preambles.

[image]

Is this a normal behavior?
Is there some elegant way to avoid that spurious filled space?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c@{}|} 
\rowcolor{gray!30}
text & text & text
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35170/colortbl-rowcolor-in-tables-with-begintabularccc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might meet your requirement

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|>{\kern-\tabcolsep}c<{\kern-\tabcolsep}|} 
\rowcolor{gray!30}
text & text & text
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The package `nicematrix` with its environment `{NiceTabular}` tries to solve the problems of the package `colortbl`.

Here is the output of `{NiceTabular}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|c@{}|}[colortbl-like]
\Hline
\rowcolor{gray!30}
text & text & text\\
\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: +1 but I'm sure you meant "problems of the colortbl package _users_" and the package itself is problem and bug free, just with a couple of unexpected features:-)

Comment: @David Carlisle: You are right. Since I'm French, it's sometimes difficult to me to express exactly what I mean in English...

Comment: sorry I was joking, your comment was perfectly correct.

Comment: Powerfull package! but I prefer not to use an external package just for this small issue.

Answer (score 2):

Do you looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c| >{\columncolor{white}[\tabcolsep][0pt]}c @{}|}
\rowcolor{gray!30}
text & text & text
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```