# rowcolor too large when removing space on rows

Tags: tables, rowcolor

I am a LaTeX beginner and facing an issue that  I can't seem to find the answer for... I am creating a table (using `booktabs` but my issue also occurs when not using the package), and whenever I remove the space on the edges of the table (with `@{}`) and try to colour individual rows at the same time, the space taken by the colour is wider than the table. See the following example:

```tex
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
% [...]


\fbox{\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
foo & bar\\
\rowcolor[HTML]{BFBFBF} bar & foo
\end{tabular}}
```

Which results in the following:

[image: rowcolor is too wide!]

Thanks in advance for any help/pointer!

Comment: Related: [colortbl: \rowcolor in tables with \begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35170/134144)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX

Comment: @leandriis the thread you linked pointed me in the right direction, thank you. I started playing with `\tabcolsep`. The solution i found is to prepend `>{\columncolor{white}[\tabcolsep][0pt]}` to my first column and `>{\columncolor{white}[0pt][\tabcolsep]}` to my last column. I am aware it's a dirty hack but it seems to do the job (and my PhD thesis is due in a few weeks). If anybody wants to answer this to my question I'll accept it!

Answer (score 5):

You could use `NiceTabular` from the `nicematrix` package instead:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\definecolor{mygray}{HTML}{BFBFBF}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}


\fbox{\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}ll@{}}[code-before=\rowcolor{mygray}{2}]
foo & bar\\
 bar & foo
\end{NiceTabular}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remark: It's not mandatory to define a color `mygray`. It's possible to write `code-before = \rowcolor[HTML]{BFBFBF}{2}`.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest setting `\fboxsep` to $0$ instead, and keeping the spaces at both ends of the table, loading `cellspace` for the vertical spacing at the top and bottom of the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}
% [...]
\begin{document}

{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\fbox{%
\begin{tabular}{Sll}
foo & bar\\
\rowcolor[HTML]{BFBFBF} bar & foo
\end{tabular}}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]